# android studio app running on api level 23 but crashes on 19

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio

this is the log cat i got every time i run the app with an AVD having

> 07-15 07:29:32.699 19719-19719/software.jain.eduvisor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: software.jain.eduvisor, PID: 19719
>                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{software.jain.eduvisor/software.jain.eduvisor.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class EditText
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class EditText
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                                                                               at software.jain.eduvisor.Home.onCreate(Home.java:38)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                            Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02007d a=-1 r=0x7f02007d}
>                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2073)
>                                                                               at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:806)
>                                                                               at android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:60)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:60)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:56)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
>                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                                                                               at software.jain.eduvisor.Home.onCreate(Home.java:38) 
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
>                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

hoping someone help
{

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="software.jain.eduvisor.Home"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:hint="@string/email_or_mobile"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#c0c0c0"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_below="@+id/username"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/username"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#c0c0c0"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vpn_key_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:id="@+id/login_btn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/password"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:drawablePadding="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_layout" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/don_apos_t_have_account"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/reg"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/register_today"
            android:id="@+id/reg"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:textColor="#fbb321"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/logintext"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:tag="0"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginTop="140dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

}
```

Comment: Post your XML please

Comment: Hi Jack, and welcome to SO. If you take a little tour of the questions asked and well answered here, you'll see it is better to post the parts of the code you think must be improved.
Take your time to format and rephrase your question please. 
read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Where is located your drawable called "ic_email_black_24dp" (drawable, drawable-hdpi, etc.)? What's its format (PNG, JPG, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove :

```
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

after googling everywhere all the day ,I found it my self, android studio created new drawable folder with name drawable-v21 and i had stored some of my drawables there so everytime when i run the app with AVD having api 19 sdk it does not recognise the path of drawables stored in drawable-v21 folder and it throws error.
that's my silly mistake